# Setting the ContextMenuStrip for all nodes on a level in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, contextmenustrip

I'm really struggling with coming up with a clever way to set the correct ContextMenuStrip for the the right node. I have a Tree View with 3 levels. And alongside with it I have 3 different ContextMenuStrips that I've created, each for their respected levels. Is there a simple way or trick that anyone's come across for solving this problem?

Also is there a way to have it so right clicking a node makes it the selected node? Or aka does the same thing as a left click.

Sorry for the 2 in 1 but I imagine if someone knows enough on this topic to solve one of my problems there's a good chance they'll know the second as well.

EDIT: I found a solution to my second problem with this line of code:

```
treeView.NodeMouseClick += (sender, args) => treeView.SelectedNode = args.Node;
```

Comment: @Steve win formsorry

Comment: I usually have something that returns each level of the tree in a List<TreeNode> each member of that list will have its ContextMenu assigned. Then call TreeView.Nodes.AddRange(List.ToArray())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the NodeMouseClick event to set the ContextMenuStrip property of the selected node:

```
void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
    treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
  }

  if (e.Node.Level == 0) {
    e.Node.ContextMenuStrip = cms1;
  } else if (e.Node.Level == 1) {
    e.Node.ContextMenuStrip = cms2;
  } else  if (e.Node.Level == 2) {
    e.Node.ContextMenuStrip = cms3;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is PERFECT thank you it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Would you say you're quite familiar with the TreeView for .NET? I have some more questions about Nodes would we be able to chat here? Not sure if they have a private message option on this site. 

Basically I want to know how to add the index to the name of a node I'm about to create. My current code is: "treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add("[" + treeView1.SelectedNode.Index + "]" + selectedModule);"

However this doesn't work because it only adds the index of the parent Node. Not the new Node. How would I go about that?

Comment: @CapnJack That would be a new question.  I don't know what you are doing with that code, but it sounds like you want the children node count, something like `treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count().ToString()` instead of index.

Comment: That works -sorta- but if I go and delete a node then if I add a new one I'll have 2 nodes with the same index on my tree wouldn't I?

Comment: To give you context I have a tree where I have a single root, multiple subs of that root and then a final, third layer of subs under each of those subs in the second layer. I need my second layer nodes to be indexed in their display names.

Comment: your Idea of using thisnode.nodes.count as an index could work but when I delete a node I'd have to update all the other nodes' indexes. Is there a way to do a find and replace on a string of taking any number and replacing it with a specific number?